# how to display sticky reply form at the bottom?

Tags: html, css

How will I display a sticky reply form for chat?
the markup is this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="messages_container">
    <ol class="messages">
      <li>sample message here</li>
      <li>sample message here</li>
      <li>sample message here</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="reply">
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <textarea cols="60" rows="1" name="message"></textarea>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How will I mark-up or style the list of messages to display it with scroll that uses percent in height of #container and .messages_container?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean you want the form to be stuck to the bottom of the page, regardless of the scroll position. I would use CSS to apply a fixed positioning to the containing element.

```
.stuck {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}


<div class="stuck">
    <!-- Form goes here. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Also, remember to take into consideration that with this method, you'll have to apply sufficient padding to the bottom of the page. Otherwise the post form will hide the last bit of your content.

Comment: How will I mark-up or style the list of messages to display it with scroll that uses percent in height of #container and .messages_container?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here, but I do know that for you to use a percentage height, the height of the parent element must be explicitly set to a static value (for example 800px).

Comment: The way I layed out my chat, was with absolutely positioned framing elements along the side and bottom, and the middle contained the chat messages. Only the chat message container scrolled, while the rest of the page stayed as is. A simple way of doing this would be to have two divs, one on top, which takes most of the screen, and one on the bottom, which contains the form. The top one would be absolutely positioned at `top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 100px; left: 0;` and the bottom forum div would be `right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; height: 99px; border-top: 1px solid #000;`